# How to dynamically inject sub type dependencies in Spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

```
public class ManageVehicles{
    @Autowired
    Vehicle vehicle;
}

public inteface Vehicle{    
}

public class Ferrari implements Vehicle{    
}

public class Lamborghini implements Vehicle{    
}

public class Fiat implements Vehicle{    
}

public class Bmw implements Vehicle{    
}
```

from the UI i am selecting the vehicles, so i want that what vehicles i select from dropdown list that vehicle object
should be injected into 'vehicle'  variable declared inside ManageVehicles class. how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that using a Vehicle Factory design pattern it will be easy to return a vehicle depend of the argument that you provide in VehicleFactory getVehicle

```
public class VehicleFactory {


   public Vehicle getVehicle(String vehicleType){
      if(vehicleType == null){
         return null;
      }     
      if(vehicleType.equalsIgnoreCase("Ferrari")){
         return new Ferrari();

      } else if(vehicleType.equalsIgnoreCase("Lamborghini")){
         return new Lamborghini();

      } else if(vehicleType.equalsIgnoreCase("Fiat")){
         return new Fiat();
      }

      return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: @Erraabi Ayoub if i have configured all the beans in spring config file spring container has to create the instances of the  beans. if i use factory pattern to create the objects based on the data passed from 
ui then i think there is no use of using spring for this use case. i need to do it using features of spring  only. that's why i had to ask if there is any way in spring to achieve this use case.

Comment: Yes I understand but ,you can create & inject your VehicleFactory using spring IoC ,just I I thought that factory pattern is one of the solution for your case

Comment: still i am not able to understand will you elaborate your answer   "you can create & inject your VehicleFactory using spring IoC "